# Why does MinGW-w64 supports '%m$' notation in 'scanf', but not in 'printf'?

Tags: c, mingw, mingw-w64

In MinGW-w64, The `%m$` can be used in the function `scanf` (`__mingw_scanf`). For example:

```
int a, b;
scanf ("%2$d%1$d", &a, &b);
```

When user inputs `1 2` at runtime then enter, the value of `a` is `2` and `b` is `1`

But using `%m$` in `printf` (`__mingw_printf`) is quite different. For example:

```
printf ("%2$d %1$d\n", 123, 456);
```

this statement does not contain any errors or warnings during compile and link process. In runtime, the result should be `456 123`, but it actually prints `%2$d %1$d` in console window, regarding all characters in format string as ordinary characters.

Why does it happen in MinGW-w64?

Comment: It looks like it is not supported yet in the latest [mingw_pformat.c](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/ci/master/tree/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/mingw_pformat.c).

Comment: It was easier to support positional arguments for `scanf` because the variable arguments are all pointers. Supporting it in `printf` is harder because there is more variation in the types of the variable arguments.

Comment: @IanAbbott As far as I know, only Microsoft supports `%m$` notation in `printf` family functions. Because this feature is nonstandard, Microsoft renamed the `printf` function with `%m$` notation as `_printf_p`. The source code of the implementation of `_printf_p` is not available for the public because MSVCRT/UCRT is a  closed-source software. However, there is no `_scanf_p` function in MSVC.

Comment: The `%m$` notation is non-standard in C, but it is not just a feature of the Microsoft C library. It is standard in POSIX.1-2017.